# Greenrobot EventBus3 not posting to my subscribers

Tags: java, android, queue

In my application, I pass a `job` into the `job-queue` and in my Job queue, I've registered my `EventBus` and I am trying to `post` the event with the hopes that my `subscriber` method would receive it. I have just recently migrated from `Otto's` `EventBus` and while this way had previously worked, it is not working for greenrobots `EventBus` 3.

Here is a sample case for what I'm trying to achieve:

`TestPresenterImpl.class` (This class has been instantiated the `TestActivity.class`)

```
@Override
public void addJob(JobData jobData) {
    jobManager.addJobInBackground(new SendUpdateJob(jobData));
}

@Subscribe
@Override
public void onUpdate(JobAddedEvent event) {
    if (event.getStatus() == 1) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "test");
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    mBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    mBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

`SendUpdateJob.class` (This is the class that handles the jobs in the queue using the android-priority-job queue previously maintained by Path)

```
@Override
public void onAdded() {
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "On added");
    mBus.getDefault().register(this);
    JobAddedEvent event = new JobAddedEvent();
    event.setStatus(1);

    mBus.getDefault().post(event);
}
```

Normally this works on `Otto` but since this is a slightly different, I want to know what I'm doing incorrectly. The error I get is: ...`"SendJobUpdate and its super classes have no public methods with the @Subscribe annotation".` Am I doing something wrong here?

I've also made sure that I'm importing `import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;`
 because I've noticed others have pointed out that they have imported googles `subscribe`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `EventBus.getDefault().register(this);` should follow your Activity which your `@Subscribe` method is in, not in `mBus.getDefault().post(event);` Activity.

FirstActicity

```
public class FirstActicity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    //register should in this activity
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MainThread)
public void onEvent(MessageEvent event) {
    //eventbus notify
    Log.i("2hh", "main --- eventbus ---- updatedata");
    queryData();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}
```

SecondActivity(don't register in this activity beacuse you didn't hava any `@Subscribe` method)

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

    EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("updateData"));


}
```

}

Comment: I submitted an edit to format your answer better and focus on the useful part. Will you please copy and paste the code in your image instead of using an image? It is easier to read, to search, and to keep the link from going bad.

Comment: Ok,i'm sorry about this,,i'm a green handi didn't think about it,i will change my answer soon,thank you for your advice.